How were the original browser root stores created?
Is there any historic information available on how the original browser root stores were created?
I noticed this comment on the Wikipedia article for Thawte:

Both Verisign and Thawte had certificates in the first Netscape browsers, and were thus "grandfathered" into all other web browsers.

Related to this (hopefully suitable for one question) I'm interested in the original development of the Mozilla and Microsoft Root Store Policies.
